# Getting around the over (partition by) clause in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, partition-by, over-clause

I have been trying to run this query in order to get a rolling count of people vaccinated in different locations but have been receiving a syntax error and I am not sure what to do

Here's the query;

```
SELECT 
    dea.continent,
    dea.location,
    dea.date,
    dea.population,
    vac.new_vaccinations,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, vac.new_vaccinations)), OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location order by dea.location, dea.date)as RollingCountPeopleVaccinated
    FROM  
    CovidDeaths dea
    JOIN CovidVaccinations vac
      ON 
     dea.location= vac.location and
     dea.date= vac.date
     where dea.continent is not null
    ORDER BY
    1,2,3
```

and the result:

> Execution finished with errors.
> Result: near "BY": syntax error
> At line 161:

```
SELECT 
    dear.continent,
    dea.location,
    dea.date,
    dea.population,
    vac.new_vaccinations,
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, vac.new_vaccinations)), OVER (PARTITION BY
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Try removing the comma before `OVER`. Also, location in `ORDER BY` may be redundant since you use it as partition column.

Comment: Are you sure that you use MySQL? Your code and error message looks like ones specific for MS SQL (SQL Server).. what is the output for `select version();`?

Comment: Hi it is DB BROWSER(SQLite)